# how to get selected radion button value with label name in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
function increasePrice(checkbox) {
  var increase = parseInt(checkbox.value);
  var price_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("price-input");
  var price_span = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
  for (var i = 0; i < price_inputs.length; i++) {
    var price = price_inputs.item(i);
    var newValue = parseInt(price.value);
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      var newValue = newValue + increase;
    } else {
      var newValue = newValue - increase;
    }
    price_span.item(i).innerHTML = newValue;
    price.value = newValue;
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>Holiday Tour</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="f1">
  <label><input onclick="increasePrice(this)" type="checkbox" value="500" > Chennai Trip (Rs.500/-)</label>
  <label><input class="price-input" type="radio"  name="optradio" value="4700">  
               1 PERSON - <b>Cost Rs.<span class="price">4700</span>/- </b>
               </label>
</form>
<p>how to display above checked amount to the below field</p>
<p><label><input type="radio" name="optradio">  
               Full Payment    <b>Cost Rs  /-</b>
               </label></p>
<p><label><input type="radio" name="optradio">  
               Advance Payment    <b>Cost Rs  /-</b>
               </label></p>
<p>Tour Package : </p>
```

i am not able to display the checked radio button value to the full amount field. i have 10 tour package and trip details when some one click the particular trip corresponding trip amount and the tour name will display

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I created a new Javascript function to update the full price radio button and label. You can use a similar method for the advance payment. I would actually just call the update advance payment method every time `updateFullPayment` is called so that they stay in sync that way.

```
 function updateFullPayment(radio) {
   var value = parseInt(radio.value)
   var full_payment = document.getElementById("full-price");
   var full_payment_radio = document.getElementById("full-price-radio");
   full_payment.innerHTML = value;
   full_payment_radio.value = value;
 };
```

I also updated your Javascript function to call mine and pass in the currently selected price so that the full price is always updated.

```
 function increasePrice(checkbox) {
   var increase = parseInt(checkbox.value);
   var price_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("price-input");
   var price_span = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
   for (var i = 0; i < price_inputs.length; i++) {
     var price = price_inputs.item(i);
     var newValue = parseInt(price.value);
     if (price_inputs.item(i).checked) {
       var selectedPrice = price_inputs.item(i);
     }
     if (checkbox.checked) {
       var newValue = newValue + increase;
     } else {
       var newValue = newValue - increase;
     }
     price_span.item(i).innerHTML = newValue;
     price.value = newValue;
 }

   updateFullPayment(selectedPrice);
 };
```

HTML now looks like this. Clicking on a price radio button will call the update function I created.

```
<h1>Holiday Tour</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="f1">
<label><input onclick="increasePrice(this)" type="checkbox" value="500" > Chennai Trip (Rs.500/-)</label>
<label><input onclick="updateFullPayment(this)" class="price-input" type="radio"  name="optradio" value="4700">
                                                          1 PERSON - <b>Cost Rs.<span class="price">4700</span>/- </b>
                                                          </label>
</form>
<p>how to display above checked amount to the below field</p>
<p><label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="full-price-radio">
                                                          Full Payment    <b>Cost Rs<span id="full-price"></span>/-</b>
                                                          </label></p>
<p><label><input type="radio" name="optradio">
                                                          Advance Payment    <b>Cost Rs  /-</b>
                                                          </label></p>
<p>Tour Package : </p>
```

Comment: GrantSlay its working fine. i need one more help how to calculate advance payment, i need to show 50% of the full payment. also when user click the 1 person radio button the corresponding tour name will display in payment page???